# installation error on mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, database

I installed MongoDB on ubuntu 11.04 followed by [this](http://bradylove.com/2011/06/06/installing-mongodb-1-8-1-on-ubuntu-11-04) site. I gave this command to run MongoDB

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start
```

It showed some error like this

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/mongodb: command not found
```

I checked the file.But it was okay.Can any one tell me how to solve this.

Please help me .I am newbie to mongoDB.
[edited] When I am connecting to mongo it is showing error like

```
connecting to: test
Sun Jul  3 09:57:29 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:79
```

Comment: What happens when you say 'which mongod'. If it cannot find it, then you missed the step to add the contents of $MONGO_INSTALLATION/bin into /bin like the author of the blog says. Also, I'd recommend using 10gen's instructions like the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You may should try to run:

```
mongo --nodb
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the connection error, you can try:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair
```

This starts the daemon using the config file */etc/mongodb.conf* and repair the database.

Then start the database:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
```